# How to add an extension number in twilio click to call using node js

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-click-to-call, twilio-programmable-voice

As per the documentation [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/click-to-call-node-express) & the github source code [here](https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/clicktocall-node), I have cloned the application, its working perfectly.

Suppose if my sales person having some extension then how can I give that extension in this script. Normally, using senddigit I can pass the extension in twilio  but I dont know how to implement that with this salesNumber.

```
  twilioClient.createCall(salesNumber, phoneNumber, headersHost)
    .then((result) => {
    response.send({message: result});
    })
    .catch((error) => {
    response.status(500).send(error);
    });
```

Please some one help on this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking at the wrong code snippet here. The code above doesn't call the Twilio client directly. Instead, it calls the helper function from [this file](https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/clicktocall-node/blob/main/lib/twilioClient.js) to initiate the call.

Once the user picks up, they will be connected to the sales person via TwiML in this function:

```js
  voiceResponse: (salesNumber, Voice = VoiceResponse) => {
    let twimlResponse = new Voice();

    twimlResponse.say('Thanks for contacting our sales department. Our ' +
                      'next available representative will take your call. ',
                      { voice: 'alice' });
    twimlResponse.dial(salesNumber);

    return twimlResponse.toString();
  }
```

In this function, you'll be able to send digits along as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43291525/how-to-send-digits-in-twilio-call).