# Twilio Make call and send digits multiple times using DTMF

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php, twilio-twiml, twilio-click-to-call

**Scenario**: I want to dial a number where an IVR is setup. That has press 1 for English and press 2 for Spanish. Once a number is chosen then it asks for 6 digit key. `How I can pass the next 6 digits using DTMF?`

I had read the documentation thoroughly and searched on StackOverflow too but didn't got the relevant data. 
**What I tried is;**

```
$twilio = new Client("AC8b2cc96be2a8dbc059f2908exxxxxxxx", "88db8eeb71124a3effd6c196xxxxxxxx");
$from = "+1289724xxxx";

$to = "+1289670xxxx";

$call = $twilio->calls
               ->create($to, // to
                        $from, // from
                        [
                            "method" => "GET",
                            "sendDigits" => "wwwwwwwwww1",
                            "sendDigits" => "wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww123456", // Whithout this line it's working for first digit press
                            "url" => "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml"
                        ]
               );

print($call->sid);
```

I am trying it using PHP Rest API. https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/make-calls#example-3
I had also read this question: [How to send digits in twilio call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43291525/how-to-send-digits-in-twilio-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't send the same parameter twice, instead, you should combine that `sendDigits` parameter into one string, like this:

```php
$call = $twilio->calls
               ->create($to, // to
                        $from, // from
                        [
                            "method" => "GET",
                            "sendDigits" => "wwwwwwwwww1wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww123456",
                            "url" => "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml"
                        ]
               );
```

Then it will wait, press 1, wait some more then press 123456.

Comment: Also How I can record this call? @philnash

Comment: Pass `”record” => true` when you create the call.

Comment: how I can then get the .mp3 file from this recording.

Comment: I had updated the url path and in request response get like this `https:\/\/api.twilio.com\/2010-04-01\/Accounts\/AC8b2xxx\/Recordings\/RE8f9a8ce822xxx`

Comment: Check out [the documentation on downloading a recording](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/recording#fetch-a-recording-media-file).